# Combine two SQLite databases in bash

Tags: sqlite, bash

I have two databases that are created in a bash file, let's call them `1.sqlite` and `2.sqlite`.  I'd like to combine them into a new database (`3.sqlite`).  Is there a command in bash that'll do that?

Edit:

The answer that sputnick gave me got me on the right track.  But I had to rearrange it to be:

```
sqlite3 1.sqlite .dump > tempdb.sqlite
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, try the following `shell` code:

```
sqlite3 .dump 1.sqlite > dump
sqlite3 .dump 2.sqlite >> dump
sqlite3 3.sqlite < dump
```

But take care of table collisions if they have the same names.

Comment: Without intermediate file ([source](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/How-do-you-combine-two-SQLite-databases-td19362.html)):
`sqlite3 .dump 1.sqlite | sqlite3 3.sqlite` and
`sqlite3 .dump 2.sqlite | sqlite3 3.sqlite`